# how to work only on one field of ValuesQuerySet - Django

Tags: python, django

I am stuck in this small issue: i have this query:

```
 studiengaenge = Studiengang.objects.values('studiengaenge').filter(kurzname__icontains=kurzname)
 res = studiengaenge.cleaned_data['studiengaenge'].split('@')
```

it is giving me the error saying that:

```
'ValuesQuerySet' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

I will have a tuple in `studiengaenge` of this kind : `['studiengaenge':'blablabla@blabla@']`

i want to split the `blablabla@blabla@` by `@` to normal array of strings. how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your queryset doesn't have a cleaned_data attribute. Why should it? That's for forms.

You can get one of the elements by slicing, just like any other queryset.